# Kotlin, NoSuchMethodError on the get [ ] operator

Tags: kotlin, nosuchmethoderror

I have this code in a third part library of [mine](https://github.com/elect86/uno-sdk/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/glsl/Program.kt):

```
class Program {

    val uniforms = HashMap<String, Int>()    
    operator fun get(s: String) = uniforms[s]!!
}
```

When I use the `[ ]` operator

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformColor.uniforms["cameraToClipMatrix"], 1, false, matBuffer)
```

I get this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: glsl.Program.get(Ljava/lang/String;)I

Why?

Everything seems fine

```
uniformColor.uniforms.contains["cameraToClipMatrix"]
```

returns true and if not, it should just return `null`

What am I missing?

kotlin 1.1-rc-91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug in Kotlin compiler.

`Map.get` in Java is Object->Object, and K->V in Kotlin.

I suspect it causes the implementation generate `fun get(s: String):Any?` and call site tries to find `fun get(s: String):Int`.

Comment: It looks like it's a bug on that RC version, this works fine in v1.0.6

Comment: Did anyone file a bug report for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the example I tried, and it works for me (even when calling it from Java) on 1.1.0-rc-91. What am I missing?

```
class Program {

    val uniforms = HashMap<String, Int>()

    operator fun get(s: String): Int = uniforms[s]!!

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val program = Program()

    program.uniforms.put("hello", 42)

    println(program["hello"])

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you remove `: Int` on the `[ ]` operator (and probably add it as a dependency)

Comment: Oh, right. Removing the explicit type and using it from another file does get me the error you're facing.

Comment: Update: Kotlin 1.1 has just been just released, and I can no longer reproduce the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can still do.. uff

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I double checked now and it turns out I just messed up the test. Still crashes. Sorry.

Comment: That's conforting somehow :p